# How can I authenticate the origin of an email?

Tags: authentication

I just received an email that seemingly comes from Microsoft (invites@microsoft.com). Apart from asking Microsoft, is there a way to properly authenticate an email's origin with public key etc? (Especially from a company like MS or google?)

I just finished an Crypto intro course and am just curious about this in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but all the reliable methods are *optional*:

- PGP signing (also depends on you already having a large PGP network or directly having accepted the real senders public key)
- x509 signing (S/MIME) - which few people use, despite [relatively painless setup](https://www.comodo.com/home/email-security/free-email-certificate.php) on the signing side
- [DMARC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489) - which probably isn't supported in your mail user agent but is gaining wide adoption in MTAs.
- [Sender Policy Framework](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction) - again is probably ignored by your user agent but commonly implemented in MTAs - Not as robust as the methods above which use cryptographic signatures.

A further issue with all of these technologies is that they are designed as means for computers to validate the identity of other computers rather than as a way of proving to human beings that an email is genuine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was under the impression that common email protocol has some "bread crumbs" that lead back to the where it came from with some crypto magic. I will look into the DMARC, sounds interesting.

Comment: You can see the chain of "received-from" headers - but this is trivial to forge